# Using categories in permalink generation

Tags: hugo

I'm trying to transition a site from Jekyll to Hugo. My main issue is I can't seem to be able to recreate the following permalink in Hugo.

```
permalink: "/:categories/:title/"
```

From the [permalink page](https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#permalink-configuration-values), it seems like:

```
[permalinks]
    post = "/:sections/:title/"
```

should work. However, `sections` relates to the [virtual location of the file within the project’s content directory](https://gohugo.io/content-management/organization/#paths-explained).

I'm wondering if theres anyway to leave the frontmatter intact? (E.g. avoid creating